# Can I pass parameters to the __iter__ function in Python?

Tags: python

I want to pass a parameter to control the size of yielded data.
For example,

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_data = list(range(23))

    def __iter__(self, size):
        random.shuffle(self.all_data)
        batch = list()
        for i in self.all_data:
            batch.append(i)
            if len(batch) >= size:
                yield batch
                batch = list()

a = Something()
for i in a:  # TypeError: __iter__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'
    print(i)
for i in a(5):  # TypeError: 'Something' object is not callable
    print(i)
```

Comment: `__iter__` must return an iterator, whatever you're doing should go in `__next__` (without any additional parameter, take parameters when doing initialization and use those attributes).

Comment: @heemayl It is possible to pass in the `size` parameter during initialization. But this means that an instance can only set one `size` parameter. The yielded data size cannot be dynamically adjusted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get your desirable effect by implementing **__call__** method which will collect data for **__iter__** to use, I set self.size in **init** constructor to ensure attribute existence.

It's not exactly what you want because it's not passing argument directly but via object's state, but it's working in case of `for i in a(5)`

please consider case when someone will use your code like this `for i in a` and by that, it can alter logic, you can check if self.size isn't **None** for example.

```
import random


class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.all_data = list(range(23))
        self.size = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        random.shuffle(self.all_data)
        batch = list()
        for i in self.all_data:
            batch.append(i)
            if len(batch) >= self.size:
                yield batch
                batch = list()

    def __call__(self, n):
        self.size = n
        return self


a = Something()

for i in a(0):
    print(i)
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that `for i in a` doesn’t call the `__call__()` method.

Comment: But it makes sense right? If you don't use parenthesis ex. `for i in a` then it will use iter by default with whatever is `self.size`

Answer (score 0):

i think it would be clearer to create a function that returns an iterator. or pass it in init

```
def __init__(self, data):
    #your code

for i in Something(42): pass
```